# Проверка файла на валидность

Tags: php, gd, mime

У меня имеется PHP код

```
$time = mktime();
if ($_FILES['foto']['size'][0] > 0) {
    if ($_FILES['foto']['type'][0] == 'image/jpeg')
        $foto = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'][0]);
    if ($_FILES['foto']['type'][0] == 'image/gif')
        $foto = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'][0]);
    if ($_FILES['foto']['type'][0] == 'image/bmp')
        $foto = imagecreatefrombmp($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'][0]);
    if ($_FILES['foto']['type'][0] == 'image/png')
        $foto = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'][0]);
    $foto_1 = '1_' . $time . '.png';
    imagepng($foto, 'images/big_images/1_' . $time . '.png');
    imagedestroy($foto);
}
```

А проблема такова: когда я заливаю кривой файл (поврежденный) формата gif, мне выдает ошибку типа

> `Error code:
> Warning: imagecreatefromgif() [function.imagecreatefromgif]: 'Z:\tmp\php32D.tmp' is not a valid GIF file in Z:\home\localhost\sort\api.php on line 21
> Warning: imagepng(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in Z:\home\localhost\sort\api.php on line 25
> Warning: imagedestroy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in Z:\home\localhost\sort\api.php on line 26`

Тут-то все ясно, но как сначала проверить файл на его валидность, а потом уже модифицировать?

Comment: imagecreatefrombmp ??? в 2017 году такой функции нет (?) Мне нужно обработаь бмп-файл, поэтому и наткнулся на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала подавить вывод ошибок функций `imagecreatefrom*()`, а потом проверять полученный результат. В [случае неудачной загрузки они возвращают](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) `false`.

```
if ($_FILES['foto']['type'][0]=='image/png')
    $foto=@imagecreatefrompng ($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'][0]);

if($foto){
    imagepng ($foto, 'images/big_images/1_'.$time.'.png');
    imagedestroy ($foto);
}else{
    echo 'Картинка содержит ошибки и не загружается';
}
```