# преобразовать конвертировать x-ms-bmp в формат подходящий для imagecreatefromХХХ

Tags: php, gd, imagemagick, конвертация, обработка-изображений

Нужно сдедать ресайз **image/x-ms-bmp** файла. Но функции imagecreatefrombmp нет. Схожие ф-ции (imagecreatefromwbmp, imagecreatefromxpm,imagecreatefrompng, imagecreatefromjpeg) возвращеют ошибку (и это понятно).

Думаю что нужно, именно в случае бмп-файла, преобразовать его в jpeg. А далее все понятно.

Но как его конвертировать? Что нужно доставить\включить на сервер(-ре)?

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exif-imagetype.php

---

Кажись, нашел (2 коммент) https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php - буду разбирать как работает...

Скопипастил - не работает :(.

**upd:** 3 коммент на стр https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php РАБОЧИЙ, но хотелось бы проще (и так чтобы я смог понять что и как работает)

---

link
[Проверка файла на валидность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83351/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Изучите строение BMP и поймете. =)

Comment: Больше пользы будет если буду думать на ООП. http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.setformat.php печально но я пока что в полшага от понимания ООП.

Comment: Стоп. Вы хотите bmp сделать из большего в меньший?  так как и с jpg и с png и другими? или вы хотите из bmp конвертнуть в jpg или png?